# Can an Excel add-in built for Excel 2010 work in Excel 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2010

I have an Excel Add in , which is built in Visual Studio using C#.

This add-in was designed for Microsoft Excel 2010, but I want to know if it is possible to run the same add-in in excel 2013.

I am getting the following error:

> You cannot debug or run this project because the following version on microsoft office is not installed

Is there any way to run the same code for Excel 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, but it searches for Office 2010 by default. If you have Office 2013 installed, it can't find it.

You should provide the startup executable to Visual Studio. You have to set the `Start external program` in the project properties to the `Excel` executable. At my desktop it is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE`.

[image]

Comment: Hey Patrick. Thanks for your reply .The code seems to be running fine, but still I do not see the desired output in the Excel Sheet. When the code runs it launches the Excel but I am unable to Print the string in Range("A1") that I have mentioned.

Comment: I guess that is better for a separate question, with the code you are using. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, will figure that out. Thank you so much. :)